# Python git downloading Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, git, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to download a Jupyter Notebook from git. I downloaded the notebook by right clicking on the file and saving it.
It is an ipynb file, but the file size seems a bit big to me for the content that it should contain (114 kb). When I click on the Notebook in Jupyter I get the following error:

Unreadable Notebook: C:\filename.ipynb NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: '\n\n

how can this error be solved and can I be able to open the Notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably downloaded the html github uses to display a notebook. To download the notebook itself, you can use the "raw" file link in github.

Answer (score 1):

you can also grab the notebook with a `wget` using the raw github link (note if the link contains a token you may have to delete the portion after the .ipynb extension before opening the file with jupyter notebook)

for example: click on the notebook's download button in github, then open the terminal and type something like `wget https://raw.githubusercontent/the_notebook_i_want.ipynb`

Comment: There is no wget on a Mac but you can use curl. Just replace wget in the example with `curl -O `