# How to get "raw" ipynb file from Google Colab using sharing url & command line?

Tags: python, command-line, download, google-colaboratory

The "sharing url" obtained for Google Colab links to a file with lots of extra HTML, so when you try to download it using wget or curl, you don't get a valid Jupyter .ipynb file.

How does one go about obtaining the file itself using command-line tools such as wget or curl?  (Note: I'm talking about "public" sharing URLs, where "anyone with the URL can view".  And I'd rather not have to use specialized google-drive command-line API tools that may require authentication, etc.)

[GitHub has a "raw" button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46800750/4259243) you can press that'll give you a valid URL for downloading Jupyter notebook files, but I don't see any such thing in Colab.  Maybe there's some kind of "`?form=raw`" thing one can add to the URL?

Alternatively, is a there a recommended script for stripping out all the extra HTML and just leaving the JSON for the .ipynb file?

**Clarification:** I'm not talking about manually moving the mouse inside Colab and clicking "File > Download > Download ipynb"; that's easy!  I'm talking about programatically getting the file using the "sharing URL".

Comment: Workaround: This does not directly answer what I asked, but may be good enough: Colab has a "Save to GitHub" feature.  By saving to GitHub, and then using the "raw" URL on GitHub,... this may suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, via [this post](https://www.matthuisman.nz/2019/01/download-google-drive-files-wget-curl.html): You just need to extract the "file id" from the url!

If the sharing url is
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SxJJc6LsKrjWAM-HhwPrLJBpUzImO5oX?usp=sharing

then the fileid is everything between the "drive/" and the question mark.

A little bash example...

```sh
$ export fileid=1SxJJc6LsKrjWAM-HhwPrLJBpUzImO5oX
$ wget -O downloaded_file.ipynb 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id='$fileid
```

...and the result is a valid Jupyter file at downloaded_file.ipynb.  :-)

Putting all this in a handy `bash` function can then look like this:

```sh
grabcolab() { fileid=$( echo "$1" | sed -E 's/.*drive\/(.*)\?.*/\1/' ); wget -O colab.ipynb 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id='$fileid; }
```

Then we just run `grabcolab <sharing url>` as in:

```sh
grabcolab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SxJJc6LsKrjWAM-HhwPrLJBpUzImO5oX?usp=sharing
```

**PS**- Off-topic but if you want to *run* the notebook from the command line, `jupytext` (installable via `pip install jupytext`) is working for me a bit better than `jupyter notebook --to-script`, so what I'm using to run the notebook is

```sh
nbrun() { jupyter nbconvert --to script "$1";  mv  "${1%.*}".py run_this.ipy; ipython run_this.ipy;}
```

As in

```sh
$ grabcolab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SxJJc6LsKrjWAM-HhwPrLJBpUzImO5oX?usp=sharing
$ nbrun colab.ipynb
```