# Download ipynb from colab notebook Url

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Given a list of colab notebooks how can I download the ipynb of each one of them using wget or curl?

- https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb
- https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization.ipynb
- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sVsoBd9AjckIXThgtZhGrHRfFI6UUYOo

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66769956/how-to-get-raw-ipynb-file-from-google-colab-using-sharing-url-command-line) explains how to download notebooks stored on gdrive, but what about notebooks stored on github or on colab directories (colab.research.google.com/notebooks/) or other sources?

Answer (score 1):

There're 2 options I recommend, assuming all the target url are in a text file. Save the code to .sh file (e.g `dlnb.sh`) and all the urls in a text file (e.g `list.txt`) like

```
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization.ipynb
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sVsoBd9AjckIXThgtZhGrHRfFI6UUYOo
```

***tl;dr***: I would recommend to use solution 2 which use [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown) (just run `pip install gdown`). Since wget can't save notebook with url doesn't have its name. Then run `bash dlnb.sh list.txt` in terminal

### 1.`wget` and `cat` only. This one has one raw back, we only use wget so the link that doesn't have a name will be save as `random_id_here.ipynb`

**dlnb.sh**

```bash
grabid() { fileid=$( echo "$1" | egrep -o '(\w|-){26,}' ); echo $fileid; }
cat $1 | while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; 
do 
    if [[ $line != *.ipynb ]]; then
        id=$(grabid "$line")
        wget -O $id.ipynb 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id='$id;
    else
        wget $line;
    fi;
done
```

I take [this reg ex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38937732), which is `egrep -o '(\w|-){26,}'` and plug it in my function, which it will extract and return id from the link

```bash
grabid() { fileid=$( echo "$1" | egrep -o '(\w|-){26,}' ); echo $fileid; }
```

assign id by calling `grabid()`, `line` is the url

```bash
id=$(grabid "$line")
```

then using `while read line || [[ -n $line ]];` loop through each `line` and download it using wget,  you can see the explantion of the while loop in the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521470)

```bash
wget -O $id.ipynb 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id='$id;
```

OR

### 2.A better solution by install [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown). This work similar as solution 1, but using `gdown` instead of `wget`

**dlnb.sh**

```bash
grabid() { fileid=$( echo "$1" | egrep -o '(\w|-){26,}' ); echo $fileid; }
cat $1 | while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; 
do 
    if [[ $line != *.ipynb ]]; then
        gdown $(grabid "$line");
    else
        gdown $line;
    fi;
done
```

If the url is not end with .ipynb `if [[ $line != *.ipynb ]];` then gdown will grab the id `$(grabid "$line");` and download it instead, while solution 1 will save the notebook as `id_of_notebook`.ipynb. `gdown` will save as its name instead.

Comment: This does not explain how to download colab links that do not have the id in the url. Like https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization.ipynb

Comment: @LeoPret both options in my answer can download without id in their url, have you read my answer? The `else
        wget $line;` is for download "colab links that do not have the id in the url" that you talk about

If you want to download the link (doesnt has id) manually just do e.g `wget your_link_here`. Please read my answer again, i have already include your example as a **.txt** file to test my code out.